# how to covert dialogic adpcm vox to wav in java

Tags: java, wav

Need to convert vox files (dialogic adpcm) to wav ones.

Do you know java solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the encoder and the decoder is documented in a [7 page format specification](http://www.salina.k-state.edu/faculty/tim/vox/dialogic_adpcm.pdf) with lots of whitespace and large diagrams, so I would suppose that you should be able to implement a decoder without much fuzz. I am pretty sure that there is no open source libraries for Java available.

Comment: Just tried to find tested solution and check my google search skills ;)
Thanks.